# How to add two animation styles to an element

Tags: css, core-animation

I am working on this CSS snippet. Why am I not able to add both pulse and fadeout animation roles to the span?

Technically I like to have both in one animation or enable to accept both pulse and fadeout animation

```css
html,body {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;

}
#point {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
position:relative;
}


.pulse {
  position:absolute;
  margin:30px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
.hideMe {
  -webkit-animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 5s;
 
}
@-webkit-keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -9999px; 
  }
}
@keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -9999px; 
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pulse hideMe"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  opacity: 1;
}

.dot--animation {
  animation:  pulse 2s infinite,
              hide .3s forwards 5s;
}
.dot--animation:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dot dot--animation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your .pulse animation with the .second animation. You need to either include both animations in the same keyframe set or seperate the keyframe sets by comma on the animate property. Alternatively you could use a wrapper, put the fadeout on the wrapper and the pulse on the actual span.
Css properties do not 'stack' on each other, they are replaced by later instances, that is true also for animate.